# Mascara em campo de form Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Boa noite, tudo certo?

Não encontro uma forma de incluir uma máscara de validação com o Form Collective do Laravel.
Abaixo o trecho do código com um campo:

```
 {{Form::label('comp_nota','Competência')}}
{{Form::text('comp_nota','',['class'=>'form-control','required','placeholder'=>'Ex: 08/2018'])}}
```

Preciso que ao digitar a competência o campo adicione a / no meio do campo. ex: 02/2018.

Ou seja, o usuário só digita 022018.

Oque posso usar galera?

Comment: {{Form::text('comp_nota','',['class'=>'form-control','required','placeholder'=>'Ex: 08/2018', pattern="[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{4}"])}}

Answer (score 0):

**Solução**: 
Uma forma de resolver é utilizar a biblioteca ***jquery.mask*** para as máscaras de seus campos.

**Exemplo de uso**:

```js
jQuery(function ($) {
    $("#comp_nota").mask("99/9999");
});
```

Answer (score -1):

**Problema**

Criar campo com input type date com [laravelcollective/html](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/master/html)

**Solução**

```
{{Form::label('comp_nota','Competência')}}
{{Form::date('comp_nota','',['class'=>'form-control','required','placeholder'=>'Ex: 08/2018'])}}
```

**Notas**

Avalie o suporte deste atributo relativamente aos diferentes browsers https://caniuse.com/#search=input%20date

Comment: Boa noite Jorge, neste caso ele fica no formato dd/mm/aaaa, eu precisava do formato mm/aaaa

Comment: Penso que o melhor neste caso seria usar uma inputmask via biblioteca em javascript

Answer (score -3):

Precisei usar essa a biblioteca jQuery-Mask-Plugin no Laravel, compartilho a minha solução.

```php
<!doctype html>
<head>
</head>
 <!-- resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php -->
<body>
    <div id="app">
        @yield('content')
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.16/jquery.mask.js"
        integrity="sha256-yE5LLp5HSQ/z+hJeCqkz9hdjNkk1jaiGG0tDCraumnA=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
<!-- Carrega o Script Personalizado na Página aqui -->
    @yield("script")

</body>
</html>
```

Formulário Cadastrar

```php
 <!-- resources/views/user/create.blade.php -->
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('script')
<script>
    $(document).ready(function($){
        $('#cpf').mask('999.999.999-99');
   });
</script>
@endsection

@section('content')
<form class="form-group" action="{{ action('UserController@store', 0) }}" method="post">
    @csrf
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <label>CPF</label><br>
        <input class="form-control" id="cpf" type="text" name="cpf" required><br>
    </div>
</form>

@stop
```